# Change metadata before download video

Tags: video, metadata

It is possible to change metadata of video before download it? For example, the user click the download link and a script write the user id into the file?

Sure, changing the metadata without saving the file in the server twice or overwrite.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: You didn't ask how. You asked if its possible. Please edit your post and put some effort into the question you really want answered.